# Passing string literal as a single prop in Typescript + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

It seems this concept is *so* basic, there's a lack of documentation about it. I can pass objects as props, but can't seem to pass a basic string literal.

### Functional Component

I have a functional component that takes a typed prop, like so:

```
const ChildComponent = (name: string) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.childComponent}>
            <p className={styles.styledName}>
                { name }
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and call it like so:

```
<ChildComponent name="testName" />
```

### Error

VSCode throws the error on `ChildComponent`:

> Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'

I'm very new to Typescript, but from what I can tell, it's reading the string literal as an object.

### Possible Solutions

Much of what I've read advises creating a custom typed prop, **even for a single property**, like so:

```
Type: NameProp {
name: string
}
```

and using that as the prop type, instead of `string`.

Isn't this overkill? Or am I missing something very basic.

Comment: You have to destructure it from props

Comment: @DecPK

Do you mean: 

`const ChildComponent = ({ name }: string) -> {
...
}`

If so, that just throws the error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'String'`

Comment: @dbcooper I've added my answer please take a look

Comment: @SergeySosunov declaring the type within curly braces throws the error `Binding element 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: It may look like an overkill, but props in React is always an object, it cannot be a string so you must create that type, otherwise you'll lose typing benefits (like passing a number to a string prop for example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const ChildComponent = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.childComponent}>
            <p className={styles.styledName}>{name}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you Konrad, for the solution **without declaring a custom Type**.

If possible, could you explain why we need to destructure a primitive string literal? And why the prop must be typed in this fashion instead of `({ name }: string}`?

Comment: Because `string` doesn't have property named `name`. But type `{ name: string }` has property named `name`. React component requires object as props, never a single value

Answer (score 2):

You have to destructure it from `props` object.

> `props` is an object.

[`CODESADNBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-field-ng1h7o?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
const ChildComponent = (props: ChildComponentProps) => {
    const { name } = props; // CHANGE THAT YOU HAVE TO DO
    return (
        <div className={styles.childComponent}>
            <p className={styles.styledName}>{name}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

or

```
const ChildComponent = ({ name }: ChildComponentProps) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.childComponent}>
            <p className={styles.styledName}>{name}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

where `ChildComponentProps` is

```
interface ChildComponentProps {
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response!

Yes, I'm aware of that solution. But as I mentioned in the OP, I wanted to know if there's a simpler solution.

Declaring a custom type `ChildComponentProps` seems like overkill, especially when it has one (primitive) property. 

In essence, `ChildComponentProps` seems to be adding an unnecessary wrapper around `string`, just so we can destructure it. 

Is this what Typescript prefers? Or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

Define a prop interface the define the props parameter as object :

```js
interface Props{
  name:string
}
const ChildComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({name}) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.childComponent}>
            <p className={styles.styledName}>
                { name }
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Props supposed to be an object. You are not the only one using this prop object.

Note that JSX is just a syntax extension use to make it easy to read & code components.

But this code will translate into the pure javascript code,

```
const element = (
  <h1 className="greeting">
    Hello, world!
  </h1>
);
```

The above code will translate into before execute,

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  {className: 'greeting'},
  'Hello, world!'
);
```

Later this `createElement` will also return an object which will use to build the whole element tree of your application.

```
// Note: this structure is simplified
const element = {
  type: 'h1',
  props: {
    className: 'greeting',
    children: 'Hello, world!'
  }
};
```

Notice the `children` property ? Its also a prop which was not added by you but the React it self.

NOTE: Above code snippets are directly copied from React JS documentation.

---

So to answer your question,

You cannot change the type of the props object. It must be an object. The reason why you seen that error message is because you forcefully telling the type of props is an string but actually it is not.

The way you should do it is,

```
const ChildComponent: React.FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.childComponent}>
            <p className={styles.styledName}>
                { name }
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dilshan for the additional information - very helpful to know how JSX also modifies `props`. As a side note, is there any reason you prefer the `React.FC` syntax over the "normal" function expressions? Or is it purely stylistic for you?

Comment: Maybe this will [help](https://dev.to/xenoxdev/usage-of-reactfc-from-my-experience-22n7)